# how can I get a random text from txt in cypress

Tags: random, cypress, readfile

sorry I am new to cypress

I got a large txt file, it has 5000 lines of txt

all txt is divided by \n

```
12331565399
29165910115
58108651482
74656524192
70536463673
11606518282
15616508033
and more...
```

I stored this txt file in my fixtures

and in my e2e cy, I wrote

```
cy.readFile('./cypress/fixtures/list.txt')
```

it gives me all the txt file but I don't know how to pick a random txt from that file

please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without converting the 5000 lines into properly formatted JSON, by adding some processing after reading the file

```js
cy.readFile('./cypress/fixtures/list.txt')
  .then(list => {
    const strings = list.split('\n')         // convert to array

      .map(line => line.replace('\r', ''))   // depending on txt file format, 
                                             // may need to remove "\r" character

    const randomText = Cypress._.sample(strings)
    return randomText
  })
  .then(randomText => {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to convert the fixture file to JSON and then from there you have three ways to read the file, all of which will be using the lodash `_.sample()` method to pick at random.

Using `require`:

```js
const textArrayFromRequire = require('../fixtures/list.json')

it('use require', function() {
    const randomTextFromRequire = Cypress._.sample(textArrayFromRequire)
    cy.wrap(randomTextFromRequire).should('be.oneOf', textArrayFromRequire)
})
```

Using `import`:

```js
import textArrayFromImport from '../fixtures/list.json'

it('use import', function() {
    const randomTextFromImport = Cypress._.sample(textArrayFromImport)
    cy.wrap(randomTextFromImport).should('be.oneOf', textArrayFromImport)
})
```

Using `cy.fixture()`:

```js
it('use cy.fixture', function() {
    cy.fixture('list.json').then(textArrayFromFixture => {
        const randomTextFromFixture = Cypress._.sample(textArrayFromFixture)
        expect(randomTextFromFixture).to.be.oneOf(textArrayFromFixture)
    })
})
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/commit/b71739f302ff61756335323fbfb0e9f7111ae861).