# Cypress: Using same fixture file in multiple test

Tags: cypress, cypress-session

I need to pass the url and other variable in multiple tests[it-function]. For 1st test code run successfully but for 2nd test it showing error. Is there any workaround or solution? My code is as follows

```js
describe('Document Upload', function()
{
    before(function () {
        cy.fixture('Credential').then(function (testdata) {
            this.testdata = testdata
        })
    })
    //1st test
    it('Login as manager',function()  
    {
    const login = new loginPage()

    cy.visit(this.testdata.baseUrl);
    login.getUserName().type(this.testdata.userDocumentM)
    login.getPassword().type(this.testdata.passwordDocumentM)
    login.getLoginButton().click()
    //Logout
    login.getUser().click()
    login.getLogout().click()

    })
    //2nd test

    it('Create Documents',function()  
    {
    const login = new loginPage()

    cy.visit(this.testdata.baseUrl);
    login.getUserName().type(this.testdata.userDocumentM)

    })
 
})
```

The error is

[image: error]

I have tried with above and also using before function again but same error

```js
before(function () {
  cy.fixture('Credential').then(function (testdata) {
    this.testdata = testdata
  })
})
```

```js
//2nd test

  it('Create Documents',function()  
    {
    const login = new loginPage()

    cy.visit(this.testdata.baseUrl);
    login.getUserName().type(this.testdata.userDocumentM)

  })
```

Comment: Unsure of _why_ this would be the answer, but have you tried using `beforeEach()` instead of `before()`?

Comment: You can use `import` or `require` outside of your tests to set a const variable holding the data and then use it across your tests. This is a basic example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964998/17917809

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Cypress version 12 [Test Isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) was introduced. This now means the Mocha context (aka `this`) is completely cleaned between tests.

#### Mocha context

It used to be (undocumented) that the Mocha context could be used to preserve variables across tests, for example

```js
before(function () {
  cy.fixture("example.json").as('testdata')    // preserved on "this" 
})

it("check testdata 1", function () {
  expect(this.testdata).to.not.be.undefined    // passes
})

it("check testdata 2", function () {
  expect(this.testdata).to.not.be.undefined    // fails in Cypress v12
})
```

but now that does not work.

The use of Mocha context is a bit arbitrary anyway, and requires explicit use of function-style functions which is easy to forget, particularly in places like array method callbacks `Array.forEach(() => {})`.

You can still use the Cypress context to store data

```js
before(function () {
  cy.fixture("example").then(function (testdata) {
    Cypress.testdata = testdata;
  })
})

it("check testdata 1", function () {
  expect(Cypress.testdata).to.not.be.undefined     // passes
})

it("check testdata 2", function () {
  expect(Cypress.testdata).to.not.be.undefined     // passes
})
```

Note this is also undocumented and may change in the future.

---

#### Caching methods

Technically, the way to do this is to set the alias with `beforeEach()`.

The `cy.fixture()` command caches it's value, so you do not get the read overhead for each test (see [Fixture returns outdated/false data #4716](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4716#issuecomment-518528101))

There is also `cy.session()` for more complicated scenarios, which would be officially supported.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('testdata', () => {
    cy.fixture("example").then(testdata => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("testdata", testdata)
    })
  })
})

it("check testdata 1", function () {
  expect(sessionStorage.getItem("testdata")).to.not.be.undefined
})

it("check testdata 2", function () {
  expect(sessionStorage.getItem("testdata")).to.not.be.undefined
})
```

Lastly, [cypress-data-session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session) which fills a gap

From the docs

| Feature | cy.session | cy.dataSession |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Command is | official ✅ | community |
| Can cache | the browser session state | anything |
| Stability | **<s>experimental</s> !!! not in v12** | production |
| Cache across specs | yes | yes |
| Access to the cached data | no **???** | yes |
| Custom validation | no | yes |
| Custom restore | no | yes |
| Dependent caching | no | yes |
| Static utility methods | limited | all |
| GUI integration | yes | no |
| Should you use it? | maybe | yes |
| Cypress version support | newer versions | all |

---

#### Cypress.env()

This is another way that is officially supported,

```js
before(() => {
  cy.fixture("example").then(testdata => {
    Cypress.env("testdata", testdata)
  })
})

it("log my fixture 1", function () {
  expect(Cypress.env("testdata")).to.not.be.undefined    // passes
})

it("log my fixture 2", function () {
  expect(Cypress.env("testdata")).to.not.be.undefined    // passes
})
```

but there are still certain tests scenarios that reset the browser completely where this may not work.